How can I transform various sequential inserts into PostgreSQL into one transaction?
I'm implementing edit tracking for a shipment management system where changes need to be tracked across multiple related tables. Each edit to a shipment might involve changes to multiple tables in a specific order:

deliveries (main shipment info)
orders (related order details)
order_quantities (product quantities in shipment)
product_serial (serial numbers of products)
invoices (related invoice information)

I want to capture a complete snapshot of the shipment state including all related data whenever any of these tables change. I've created an edit_history table:
CREATE TABLE edit_history (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('edit_history_id_seq'),
    tstamp timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
    tabname text,
    operation text,
    who text DEFAULT CURRENT_USER,
    key jsonb,
    new_val jsonb,
    old_val jsonb,
    transaction_id bigint
);

The idea is that edit_history stores a snapshot of data at the time and highlights changes, so they can be easily compared in the front end (using PostgREST).
And I'm using a trigger function to track changes:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.delivery_edit_function()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$
DECLARE
    j_new jsonb := null;
    j_old jsonb := null;
    j_key jsonb;
    v_delivery_id bigint;
    v_transaction_id bigint;
    v_snapshot jsonb;
    v_exists boolean;
    v_changes jsonb;
BEGIN
    v_transaction_id := txid_current();
    
    -- Get delivery_id
    IF TG_TABLE_NAME = 'deliveries' THEN
        v_delivery_id := COALESCE(NEW.delivery_id, OLD.delivery_id);
    ELSIF TG_TABLE_NAME = 'order_quantities' THEN
        v_delivery_id := COALESCE(NEW.fk_delivery_id, OLD.fk_delivery_id);
    ELSIF TG_TABLE_NAME = 'product_serial' THEN
        SELECT DISTINCT oq.fk_delivery_id INTO v_delivery_id
        FROM order_quantities oq
        WHERE oq.fk_product_id = COALESCE(NEW.fk_sage_details_id, OLD.fk_sage_details_id);
    END IF;

    IF v_delivery_id IS NULL THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    -- Check for existing operation in transaction
    SELECT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM edit_history 
        WHERE transaction_id = v_transaction_id
        AND tabname = TG_TABLE_NAME 
        AND operation = TG_OP
        AND (key->>'delivery_id')::bigint = v_delivery_id
    ) INTO v_exists;

    IF v_exists THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    -- Get existing changes in transaction
    SELECT new_val INTO v_changes
    FROM edit_history
    WHERE transaction_id = v_transaction_id
    AND (key->>'delivery_id')::bigint = v_delivery_id
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1;

    -- Get or create snapshot
    IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM edit_history 
        WHERE transaction_id = v_transaction_id
        AND (key->>'delivery_id')::bigint = v_delivery_id
    ) THEN
        SELECT jsonb_build_object(
            'delivery_number', d.delivery_number,
            'status', d.status,
            'courier', d.courier,
            'order_id', o.order_id,
            'sage_sales_order_number', COALESCE(o.sage_sales_order_number, 'TBC'),
            'po_number', COALESCE(o.po_number, 'TBC'),
            'order_comments', o.order_comments,
            'invoice_number', COALESCE(i.invoice_number, 'TBC'),
            'customer_id', c2.customer_id,
            'shipment_date', COALESCE(d.shipment_date::text, 'TBC'),
            'tracking_number', COALESCE(d.tracking_number, 'TBC'),
            'shipment_origin_id', d.shipment_origin_id,
            'shipment_origin', COALESCE(d.shipment_origin, 'TBC'),
            'address_nickname', a.address_nickname,
            'contact_name', c.contact_name,
            'customer_name', COALESCE(c2.customer_name, 'TBC'),
            'products', (
                SELECT jsonb_agg(
                    jsonb_build_object(
                        'product_id', sd.sage_details_id,
                        'product_code', sd.sage_product_code,
                        'product_description', sd.sage_product_description,
                        'quantity', oq.quantity,
                        'serials', (
                            SELECT jsonb_agg(DISTINCT ps.device_serial ORDER BY ps.device_serial)
                            FROM product_serial ps
                            WHERE ps.fk_sage_details_id = sd.sage_details_id
                            AND EXISTS (
                                SELECT 1 FROM order_quantities oq2
                                WHERE oq2.fk_product_id = ps.fk_sage_details_id
                                AND oq2.fk_delivery_id = d.delivery_id
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    ORDER BY sd.sage_details_id
                )
                FROM order_quantities oq
                JOIN sage_details sd ON sd.sage_details_id = oq.fk_product_id
                WHERE oq.fk_delivery_id = d.delivery_id
            )
        )
        FROM deliveries d
        LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.order_id = d.fk_order_id
        LEFT JOIN invoices i ON i.invoice_id = d.fk_invoice_id
        LEFT JOIN contacts c ON c.contact_id = o.fk_contact_id
        LEFT JOIN customers c2 ON c2.customer_id = c.fk_customer_id
        LEFT JOIN addresses a ON a.address_id = c.fk_address_id
        WHERE d.delivery_id = v_delivery_id
        INTO v_snapshot;
    ELSE
        SELECT old_val INTO v_snapshot
        FROM edit_history
        WHERE transaction_id = v_transaction_id
        AND (key->>'delivery_id')::bigint = v_delivery_id
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 1;
    END IF;

    -- Handle changes by table
    IF TG_TABLE_NAME = 'deliveries' THEN
        IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
            SELECT jsonb_build_object(
                'products', COALESCE(v_changes->'products', '[]'::jsonb)
            ) || (
                SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
                FROM jsonb_each(to_jsonb(NEW))
                WHERE to_jsonb(NEW)->key IS DISTINCT FROM to_jsonb(OLD)->key
                AND key != 'delivery_id'
            ) INTO j_new;
        ELSIF TG_OP IN ('INSERT', 'DELETE') THEN
            j_new := jsonb_build_object(
                'products', COALESCE(v_changes->'products', '[]'::jsonb)
            ) || (to_jsonb(CASE WHEN TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN NEW ELSE OLD END) - 'delivery_id');
        END IF;
    ELSIF TG_TABLE_NAME = 'product_serial' AND TG_OP IN ('INSERT', 'UPDATE') THEN
        j_new := jsonb_build_object(
            'products', 
            COALESCE(
                v_changes->'products' || 
                jsonb_build_array(
                    jsonb_build_object(
                        'product_id', NEW.fk_sage_details_id,
                        'serials', jsonb_build_array(NEW.device_serial)
                    )
                ),
                jsonb_build_array(
                    jsonb_build_object(
                        'product_id', NEW.fk_sage_details_id,
                        'serials', jsonb_build_array(NEW.device_serial)
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    ELSIF TG_TABLE_NAME = 'order_quantities' AND TG_OP IN ('INSERT', 'UPDATE') THEN
        j_new := jsonb_build_object(
            'products',
            COALESCE(
                v_changes->'products' || 
                jsonb_build_array(
                    jsonb_build_object(
                        'product_id', NEW.fk_product_id,
                        'quantity', NEW.quantity
                    )
                ),
                jsonb_build_array(
                    jsonb_build_object(
                        'product_id', NEW.fk_product_id,
                        'quantity', NEW.quantity
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    END IF;

    -- Insert history record
    INSERT INTO edit_history (
        transaction_id, tabname, operation, who, 
        key, new_val, old_val
    ) VALUES (
        v_transaction_id, TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_OP, CURRENT_USER,
        jsonb_build_object('delivery_id', v_delivery_id),
        j_new,
        v_snapshot
    );

    RETURN NULL;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE WARNING 'Error in delivery_edit_function: %', SQLERRM;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$function$;

My issues are:

Each PostgREST API call is a separate transaction, but they're logically part of one edit session. Since I am using ng-swagger-gen and using the CRUD services it generates from the database structure. Here's an example of front-end operations:

For example creating a delivery:
// 1. Create/find order
this.ordersService.getOrders({
    sageSalesOrderNumber: `eq.${sageOrderNumber}`,
}).pipe(
    switchMap((existingOrders) => {
        if (existingOrders.length > 0) {
            return of(existingOrders[0]);
        } else {
            return this.ordersService.postOrders({
                orders: newOrder,
                Prefer: 'return=representation',
            })
        }
    }),
    // 2. Create invoice using order_id
    switchMap((orderResponse) => {
        return this.invoicesService.postInvoices({
            invoices: { 
                invoice_number: invoiceNumber,
                fk_order_id: orderResponse.order_id 
            }
        })
    }),
    // 3. Create delivery using order_id and invoice_id  
    switchMap(({order, invoice}) => {
        return this.deliveriesService.postDeliveries({
            deliveries: newDelivery
        })
    }),
    // 4. Create product serials and quantities in parallel
    switchMap(({order, invoice, delivery}) => {
        const devicePromises = filledDevices.map(device => {
            // Create serials first if needed
            const serialPromises = serialNumbers.map(serialNumber =>
                this.productSerialService.postProductSerial({
                    productSerial: { 
                        device_serial: serialNumber,
                        fk_sage_details_id: sageDetailsId
                    }
                })
            );

            return forkJoin(serialPromises).pipe(
                switchMap(() => this.orderQuantitiesService.postOrderQuantities({
                    orderQuantities: {
                        fk_order_id: order.order_id,
                        fk_delivery_id: delivery.delivery_id,
                        fk_product_id: sageDetailsId,
                        quantity: quantity
                    }
                }))
            );
        });

        return forkJoin(devicePromises);
    })
)

And editing a delivery:
// Creating new shipments
private postShipment(...) { /* shown above */ }

// Editing existing shipments
private editShipment(
    existingOrder: Orders,
    existingDelivery: Deliveries,
    filledDevices: AbstractControl[]
): void {
    // 1. Update invoice first
    const invoiceUpdate$ = this.invoicesService
        .getInvoices({
            fkOrderId: `eq.${existingOrder.order_id}`,
        })
        .pipe(
            switchMap((existingInvoices) => {
                const deliveryInvoice = existingInvoices.find(
                    (inv) => inv.invoice_id === existingDelivery.fk_invoice_id
                );

                if (deliveryInvoice) {
                    return this.invoicesService.patchInvoices({
                        invoiceId: `eq.${deliveryInvoice.invoice_id}`,
                        invoices: {
                            invoice_number: formValues.invoiceNumber || 'TBC',
                        } as Invoices
                    });
                } else {
                    return this.invoicesService.postInvoices({
                        invoices: {
                            invoice_number: formValues.invoiceNumber || 'TBC',
                            fk_order_id: existingOrder.order_id,
                        } as Invoices,
                        Prefer: 'return=representation',
                    });
                }
            })
        );

    // 2. Update order details
    const orderUpdate$ = this.ordersService.patchOrders({
        orderId: `eq.${existingOrder.order_id}`,
        orders: {
            sage_sales_order_number: formValues.salesOrder?.trim(),
            po_number: formValues.purchaseOrder?.trim(),
            order_comments: formValues.orderComments?.trim(),
            fk_contact_id: this.selectedCustomer?.contact_id,
        } as Orders
    });

    // 3. Delete and recreate all products
    const quantitiesUpdate$ = this.orderQuantitiesService
        .getOrderQuantities({
            fkDeliveryId: `eq.${existingDelivery.delivery_id}`,
        })
        .pipe(
            switchMap((quantities) => {
                if (quantities.length === 0) return of(null);

                const sageDetailsIds = quantities.map((q) => q.fk_product_id);

                // Delete all serials first
                return this.productSerialService
                    .getProductSerial({
                        fkSageDetailsId: `in.(${sageDetailsIds.join(',')})`,
                    })
                    .pipe(
                        switchMap((serials) => {
                            const deleteSerials$ = serials.length > 0
                                ? this.productSerialService.deleteProductSerial({
                                    productId: `in.(${serials.map((s) => s.product_id).join(',')})`,
                                })
                                : of(null);

                            // Then delete quantities
                            return deleteSerials$.pipe(
                                switchMap(() => this.orderQuantitiesService.deleteOrderQuantities({
                                    fkDeliveryId: `eq.${existingDelivery.delivery_id}`,
                                }))
                            );
                        })
                    );
            })
        );

    // 4. Run all updates in parallel then update delivery
    forkJoin({
        invoice: invoiceUpdate$,
        order: orderUpdate$,
        quantity: quantitiesUpdate$,
    })
        .pipe(
            switchMap(() => {
                return this.deliveriesService
                    .patchDeliveries({
                        deliveryId: `eq.${existingDelivery.delivery_id}`,
                        deliveries: {
                            shipment_date: formValues.shipmentDate,
                            courier: formValues.courier,
                            tracking_number: formValues.trackingNumber?.trim() || undefined,
                            status: formValues.deliveryStatus,
                        } as Deliveries,
                    });
            })
        )
        .subscribe({...});
}


Needs to capture complete snapshots including all related data
Changes happen in a specific order (order -> invoice -> delivery -> products)
Need to track product serials and quantities that are added in parallel

How can I track these related changes when they come as separate transactions from PostgREST?
Should I create one history record per API call, or try to group them?
Is there a better way to structure the trigger function to handle the parallel product/serial updates?
Would it be better to modify how the frontend makes API calls?
I've tried using transaction IDs and checking for existing operations, but I'm still getting multiple history records for what should be one logical edit session.
Any suggestions on improving this approach would be greatly appreciated.

"Would it be better to modify how the frontend makes API calls?" - yes. Unless you are fine with the frontend making any number of independent API calls, in any order, and having to group them afterwards to make sense of them.

Currently I thought using forkJoin would be the best approach, but I'm not sure, would you recommend something else?
